# can't get this to run properly python error

Tags: python, parsing

```
while True:
  inputstring = input("Enter input string: ") 
  "\n"

  if (inputstring == 'q'):
    break
  if ',' not in inputstring:
    print("\nError: No comma in string.")
  else:
    fname , sname = inputstring.split(',')

    fname , sname = fname.strip(), sname.strip()

    print("\nFirst word:", fname)

    print("Second word:", sname)

    print("\n")



Enter input string: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    inputstring = input("Enter input string: ") 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As StackOverflow is not meant to be used as a forum to help you debug your code. You may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO and what is expected.

Comment: How I would suggest going about this, is lookup just the last part of the error code. For example I would google `EOFError: EOF when reading a line python`.

Comment: Please state exactly what you want the program to do and be sure to follow the guidlines(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) like Suit Boy Apps said

Comment: Is there meant to be a '\n' that isn't being printed in line 3....

Answer (score 0):

Change line 3 to 'print("\n")'